# Installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on USB; Blank/Black Screen is shown when enter the USB at boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, usb

I am using HP Pavilion dv6t Quad Edition with a model number of LM720AV.

I have successfully installed the Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a 32GB Kingston microDuo 3.0 with a liveusb created by Rufus using the HP laptop.

However, the problem arises when I entered into the 32GB Kingston microDuo 3.0; it just shows a black/blank screen. Does anyone know what is the problem causing the black/blank screen on HP laptop?

There is no secure boot or legacy support options in the HP laptop's BIOS, so there is no way that I can disable the secure boot and enable the legacy support.

Also, I am pretty sure there is no problem with the Ubuntu bootloader in the 32GB USB. The Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS in 32GB USB is running fine with my old desktop (Dell pentium D).

Thanks.

Comment: If it runs fine on a Pentium 4 machine, I'm guessing you got the 32-bit version. Can you give the 64-bit version a go? You might also want to try this program for burning the ISO, but I doubt it would make a difference: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.8.exe

Comment: Sorry... my huge mistake :((. The old desktop is Pentium D not Pentium IV. The file "ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64" I downloaded from the Ubuntu website is 64bit right? "ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64" is the version I installed on the 32GB USB.

Comment: *There is no secure boot or legacy support options* and the fact it booted in a non-UEFI machine suggests you installed in Legacy mode, i.e., without the EFI partition required. Can you please check the contents of the USB to confirm?

Comment: I am still new to this kinda thing. What content do I need to check from the USB? How can I check it on Windows 7; it only shows "Removable Disk".

Comment: I have checked the partition of the 32GB USB on Windows 7. It shows 27.01GB Healthy (Active, Primary Partition) and 1.90 GB Healthy (Primary Partition).